# Boost State Machine Language - `post` event from within an `action`

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, boost-sml

I am using [boost sml](https://boost-experimental.github.io/sml/) for a few days, and I've got to the point where I need to post / process an event from within an action.
I can see that it can be done directly from the transition table:

```cpp
using namespace sml;
return make_transition_table(
 *"s1"_s + event<my_event> / process_event(other_event{}) = "s2"_s,
  "s2"_s + event<other_event> = X
);
```

But my use-case is different:
I have a state that has an `action`for `on-entry` event, which does some work, and eventually, trigger an event (from `within` the state `action`).

For example, with `boost statechart`, each state had access to the `context` and could `post_event`.

Is this possible with `sml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. You need to do 2 things.
One is setting `boost::sml::queue` template argument to `boost::sml::sm`.

```
// sml::process_queue is for post event
sml::sm<table, sml::process_queue<std::queue>> sm;
```

The posted event need to be pushed into a queue. When the current transition is finished, then the event popd from the queue and processed. In order to do that, Boost.SML require some queue. `sml::process_queue<std::queue>` provides the queue type. You can pass any types that satisfies queue concept that behaves as `std::queue`.

The other is setting `sml::back::process<comma_separated_list_of_processed_event_types>` parameter to the action handler as follows:

```
[](auto const& /*ev*/, sml::back::process<other_event /*, my_event*/ > process) {
```

The argument process is callable. So you can call `process` as a function. When you call `process(event)` then the event is posted to the queue.

Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <boost/sml.hpp>

int main() {
    namespace sml = boost::sml;

    struct my_event {};
    struct other_event {};

    struct table {
        auto operator()() const noexcept {
            using namespace sml;
            return make_transition_table(

               *"s1"_s + event<my_event> / 
                // In order to post event in the action,
                // you need to define the action handler as follows.
                // The key is the second parameter.
                // `sml::back::process` is posting event callable type.
                // You need to pass all event types that are posted in the action handler
                // as the template argument.
                // Unfortunately you cannot write `sml::back::process<_>` for all events.
                [](auto const& /*ev*/, sml::back::process<other_event /*, my_event*/ > process) {
                    std::cout << "before post" << std::endl;
                    process(other_event{});
                    std::cout << "after post" << std::endl;
                } = "s2"_s,

                "s2"_s + event<other_event> = X,

                // entry exit log
                "s1"_s + sml::on_entry<_> / [] { std::cout << "s1 on entry" << std::endl; },
                "s1"_s + sml::on_exit<_>  / [] { std::cout << "s1 on exit"  << std::endl; },
                "s2"_s + sml::on_entry<_> / [] { std::cout << "s2 on entry" << std::endl; },
                "s2"_s + sml::on_exit<_>  / [] { std::cout << "s2 on exit"  << std::endl; }
            );
        };
    };

    // sml::process_queue is for post event
    sml::sm<table, sml::process_queue<std::queue>> sm;
    sm.process_event(my_event{});
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/yueELv7SoFbPCEW1