# How to pass data to an event inside a boost::sml state machine for using the 'direct' process method?

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, boost-sml

Consider the example from the [sml documentation regarding process and defer](https://boost-ext.github.io/sml/examples.html#deferprocess),
rewritten a bit by me to pass a dependency to the state machine to be used in the event processing:

```cpp
// $CXX -std=c++14 defer_and_process.cpp
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace {
struct e1 {};
struct e2 {int dependency = 0;};
struct e3 {};
struct e4 {};

struct defer_and_process {
  auto operator()() const noexcept {
    using namespace sml;
    return make_transition_table(
       *"idle"_s + event<e1> / defer
      , "idle"_s + event<e2> = "s1"_s
      , "s1"_s   + event<e1> / process(e2{/*pass my_dependency here*/}) = "s2"_s // this is the interesting bit
      , "s2"_s   + event<e3> / process(e4{})
      , "s2"_s   + event<e4> = X
    );
  }
};
}  // namespace

int main() {
  int my_dependency = 42;
  using namespace sml;
  sm<defer_and_process, sml::defer_queue<std::deque>, sml::process_queue<std::queue>>
      sm{my_dependency}; 
  assert(sm.is("idle"_s));

  assert(sm.process_event(e1{}));
  assert(sm.is("idle"_s));

  assert(!sm.process_event(e2{}));  /// triggers idle -> s1 and s1 -> s2 (via deferred e1)
  assert(sm.is("s2"_s));

  assert(sm.process_event(e3{}));  /// triggers s2.process(e4) -> X (via processed e4)
  assert(sm.is(sml::X));
}
```

Is it possible to do that directly or...

Is the lambda way described in [Boost State Machine Language - `post` event from within an `action`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524500/boost-state-machine-language-post-event-from-within-an-action)

The only way to do it? Is inlining not possible?

Like `process(e2{some way to pull the data out of the sm dependency list and pass it here })`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the callable object is the way to go. Got it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's perfectly clear. "I need to do the callable object approach to pass dynamic data to an event processor"
I will repost this comment every time it gets deleted, provided I remember to check it, until I get an actual reason for the deletion of it, that isn't "It's unclear". 

If you can't grok "yeah I need the callable object it seems" then you're even more stupid than I am.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in a static dependency already just works. If it needs to be dynamic, then the callable object approach is required because there's no other way to access the context:

```
// $CXX -std=c++14 defer_and_process.cpp
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace {
    struct e1 {};
    struct e2 { int dependency = 0; };
    struct e3 {};
    struct e4 {};

    struct injectable {
        int dependency;
    };

    struct defer_and_process {
        auto operator()() const noexcept {
            using namespace sml;

            auto action = [](injectable& i, sml::back::process<e2> process) {
                std::cout << "posting with e2{" << i.dependency << "}" << std::endl;
                process(e2{i.dependency});
            };

            return make_transition_table(             //
                *"idle"_s + event<e1> / defer,        //
                "idle"_s + event<e2>        = "s1"_s, //
                "s1"_s + event<e1> / action = "s2"_s, //
                "s2"_s + event<e3> / process(e4{}),   //
                "s2"_s + event<e4> = X                //
            );
        }
    };
} // namespace

int main() {
    for (auto dep : {0, 42, -314}) {
        using namespace sml;
        sm<                                //
            defer_and_process,             //
            sml::defer_queue<std::deque>,  //
            sml::process_queue<std::queue> //
        > sm{injectable{dep}};

        assert(sm.is("idle"_s));

        assert(sm.process_event(e1{}));
        assert(sm.is("idle"_s));

        assert(!sm.process_event(e2{})); /// triggers idle -> s1 and s1 -> s2 (via deferred e1)
        assert(sm.is("s2"_s));

        assert(sm.process_event(e3{})); /// triggers s2.process(e4) -> X (via processed e4)
        assert(sm.is(sml::X));
    }
}
```

Note that you **can** hide that callable with some syntactic sugar. For example:

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace {
    struct injectable {
        int dependency = 0;
    };

    struct e1 {};
    struct e2 {
        int dependency;
        e2(injectable const& i = {}) : dependency(i.dependency) {}
    };
    struct e3 {};
    struct e4 {
        int dependency;
        e4(injectable const& i = {}) : dependency(i.dependency) {}
    };

    template <typename E> struct inj_process {
        void operator()(injectable& i, sml::back::process<E> process) const {
            std::cout << "posting with " << boost::core::demangle(typeid(E).name()) << "{" << i.dependency
                      << "}" << std::endl;
            process(E{i});
        };
    };

    struct defer_and_process {
        auto operator()() const noexcept {
            using namespace sml;

            return make_transition_table(                        //
                *"idle"_s + event<e1> / defer,                   //
                "idle"_s + event<e2>                   = "s1"_s, //
                "s1"_s + event<e1> / inj_process<e2>{} = "s2"_s, //
                "s2"_s + event<e3> / inj_process<e4>{},          //
                "s2"_s + event<e4> = X                           //
            );
        }
    };
} // namespace

int main() {
    for (auto dep : {0, 42, -314}) {
        using namespace sml;
        sm<                                //
            defer_and_process,             //
            sml::defer_queue<std::deque>,  //
            sml::process_queue<std::queue> //
        > sm{injectable{dep}};

        assert(sm.is("idle"_s));

        assert(sm.process_event(e1{}));
        assert(sm.is("idle"_s));

        assert(!sm.process_event(e2{})); /// triggers idle -> s1 and s1 -> s2 (via deferred e1)
        assert(sm.is("s2"_s));

        assert(sm.process_event(e3{})); /// triggers s2.process(e4) -> X (via processed e4)
        assert(sm.is(sml::X));
    }
}
```

Printing

```
posting with (anonymous namespace)::e2{0}
posting with (anonymous namespace)::e4{0}
posting with (anonymous namespace)::e2{42}
posting with (anonymous namespace)::e4{42}
posting with (anonymous namespace)::e2{-314}
posting with (anonymous namespace)::e4{-314}
```

Comment: Really wish you hadn't used "obviously" because I wouldn't have asked had it been obvious to me. I consider the dynamic approach the more true to reallife one yet in the documentation it seems to be an afterthought and kind of hidden in an example. How to not dislike you from this first impression?

Comment: Fair point. I too have seen libraries where the dynamic behavior was papered over by more complex front end (e.g. Proto based expressions in Boost Log). Inevitably the result is hard to use and Very Slow(TM) to compile. This is why I don't expect these trappings in SML, which specifically distances from the [MSM approach](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/libraries.htm).

Comment: (There are other complexities in SML that surprise me; e.g. the whole dependency injection and dynamic action/guard invocation style is way more error-prone and hard to discover than necessary to my taste. I really prefer how e.g. Boost Spirit X3 has approached this by explicitly passing context references that you can actively query for the bits you need. It's less code and zero surprises. But I digress. I hope my answer was still helpful in some way.)